# Nginx proxy pass to subfolder

Tags: nginx, devops, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have an Nginx reverse proxy and I want to proxy pass domain `abcd.com` to `example.com` subdirectory but sometimes It redirects domain `abcd.com` to `abcd.com/newsite`. how can prevent this redirection?

```
server {
   listen          443 ssl http2;
   server_name     abcd.com www.abcd.com;
   ssl_protocols       TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
   ssl_certificate   /etc/nginx/ssl/abcd.com/fullchain.pem;
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/abcd.com/privkey.pem;

   location / {
       include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
       include /etc/nginx/headers.conf;
       add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains;preload" always;
       proxy_pass http://example.com/newsite/;
   }
}
```

Comment: “sometimes It redirects domain abcd.com to abcd.com/newsite“ - when exactly this redirect occurs?

Comment: Does your server used in `proxy_pass http://example.com/newsite/;` properly processes requests to host `example.com`?